# Use declared but not defined TypeAlias in type annotation?

Tags: python, typing

UPDATE: Given answer received in comments, I have amended the question, emphasizing that what I really want to know is:

(1) Is there any *deep reason* Python's type system does not allow what I want to accomplish? (Or is it, for example, just how it happens to be implemented.)

Also, if the answer to (1) is negative I guess I would be interested in an answer to:

(2) Is there any other way (in Python) to accomplish what I try to?

Original (only slightly edited) question below.

---

I am using Python 3.10.4 and excitedly trying out what now seems to be a quite mature type system (at least compared to when I last did some serious Python stuff).

However, using a declared but not defined TypeAlias in a type annotation does not work but gives a runtime error. Why? Theoretically, I see no problem in my particular case,¹ but perhaps there is some *deeper reason* for why Python's type system works this way? (Pyright errors when I try to define the TypeAlias after its declaration so perhaps there are good reasons that one should not do this. Also, this causes Pyright to not report a later type violation.)

In more detail, consider the following examples, with runtime errors and Pyright error pointed out in comments.

First example, demonstrating what I am trying to do:

```
from typing import Literal, Final, TypeAlias


# PUBLIC_INTERFACE

a_type_alias : TypeAlias

# the following gives the runtime error:
# “NameError: name 'a_type_alias' is not defined. Did you mean: 'TypeAlias'?”
A_SET : Final[set[a_type_alias]]


# IMPLEMENTATION

a_type_alias = Literal[0,1] # Pyright error: “"a_type_alias" is declared as a
                            # TypeAlias and can be assigned only once”

A_SET = {0,1,2} # Pyright reports no error, but should be a type violation per
                # lines 10 and 15?
```

Second example, demonstrating everything working:

```
from typing import Literal, Final, TypeAlias

a_type_alias : TypeAlias = Literal[0,1]

A_SET : Final[set[a_type_alias]]

# Pyright correctly reports type violation on the following assignment
A_SET = {0,1,2}
```

¹ By this, I mean that the type annotation `A_SET : Final[set[a_type_alias]]` in the examples does not need the value of `a_type_alias` until type-checking `A_SET`, which in my examples happens when the value of `a_type_alias` is known.

Comment: `a_type_alias : TypeAlias` annotates that `a_type_alias` is a type of `TypeAlias`, but it does not define what it actually is. So yes, that won't work. The type annotation system just works with regular *variables*, and `set[a_type_alias]` needs to use the *value* of that variable at that time. If it doesn't have a value at that time, that doesn't work.

Comment: *Assignment is declaration.* This isn't C, you can't separate the "interface" from the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I suspected something like that. However, purely theoretically and ignoring Python specifics, the annotation of `A_SET` using `set[a_type_alias]` does not need to use the value of `a_type_alias` until it needs to type check `A_SET`, which in my first example happens after `a_type_alias` has been defined. That is why I asked if there is a deeper reason why my first example does not work, other than the specifics of Python's current implementation of its type system.

Comment: Regarding separating interface and implementation, that seems to be possible for non-type-variables. I have amended my second example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Well, in that later example, you're not trying to use *the value* of `A_SET` before assigning it, so there's no issue. — In the abstract, anything is possible, if the language defines it to be possible. But what you're trying to do is not defined as possible in Python.

Comment: I perfectly understand that much, thanks. I have amended the question again to clearly emphasize what I am asking. Apologies if my original formulation was not clear enough (or if my current formulation  is not clear enough).

Comment: *"Is there any __deep reason__ …"* — Again, because it's all just runtime code and just follows the same working as any other Python code. You're essentially doing `foo` `bar = baz(foo)`. That also doesn't work, because while you have "mentioned" `foo` before, you haven't _assigned_ anything to it, so `baz(foo)` can't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, with the drawback that `a_type_alias` is not explicitly declared under the `# PUBLIC INTERFACE` part. I looked at [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) and initially used a solution with `from __future__ import annotations` but turns out Pyright (verison 1.1.247) type checks the following with or without that future import.

```
from typing import Literal, Final, TypeAlias


# PUBLIC_INTERFACE

set_1 : Final[set['a_type_alias']]
set_2 : Final[set['a_type_alias']]


# IMPLEMENTATION

a_type_alias : TypeAlias = Literal[0,1]

set_1 = {0}   # no error from Pyright (correct)
set_2 = {0,2} # error from Pyright (correct)
```